# Adobe Illustrator graph tool falsely rounds numbers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I enter a number like 1839986 in a cell, Illustrator rounds it to 1839990. It is even worse for numbers with more digits.

I need to produce infographics on a constant basis. What's the remedy?

Comment: Why do you use illustrator to make graphs?

Comment: Because I need to produce printable CMYK infographics from Excel data, and Excel's "design capabilities" are insufficient for my purpose

Comment: Yes but there are way more graphing applications than excel. That are also way more suited to your job. You can bark up this tree as much as you want it is not going top change. If your primary job is info graphics get one of the free or not so free scientific visualization applications a spin.

Comment: Well, I'm not using Excel. The corporate data comes from Excel. I'm using Adobe Illustrator and Adobe InDesign to produce large corporate reports. That Adobe software made for handling data is apparently incapable of handling data correctly is amateurish. So, which CMYK workflow applications for graphing data that work well with InDesign are there?

Comment: maybe tikz, or write your own in PostScript (really adobes graph tool takes an hour to best from 0 level). but changing color should be your last concern. I would suggest mathematica for all ones graphing needs but something tells me you can not afford it.

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica is very low price compared to stock and financial analysis software. The problem is we are graphic designers for print, not mathematicians. I had hoped either Adobe will get its act together or there would be a software for diagramming integrating into the Adobe workflow.

Comment: Yes but we can not affect what adobe does. You can integrate Any software capable of making PDF or EPS files into Adobe workflow. Indesign and illustrator do not actually care what the application is they will happily place any PDF of EPS as if it was generated by an adobe application (that's why the developed PS and PDF). Mathematica is not really for mathematicians, its for anybody who wants to quickly get a decent result out of a data analysis. Including school children. But are you saying that itsat adobe than spend an hour learning something worthwhile that fixes your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use it as is.  Only programmers have a theoretical possibility to increase Illustrator's internal calculation & number presentation resolution.

If your units were usual screen pixels, your image would be about 639 meters wide or high. That's for 4 px error. One pixel error needs about 160 meters. I guess this big screens with 72 DPI resolution are still unavailable.

Have the exact numbers stored elsewhere just in case they are needed for something, for ex. if one wants to divide them to prime numbers.

Comment: Pardon me, but this is not about screen pixels or image sizes, but Illustrator's graph tool rounding numbers in cells when producing infographics (charts). When designing financial publications for SEC filings, for example, numbers must be correct, not approximated

Comment: Nobody has claimed it's about pixels or image size. The internal number presentation in programs rarely is as typed numbers in normal 10 digit system, internally programs use binary integers or binary floating point numbers. That's for math efficiency. The external form isn't stored, so you must do it by yoursjälv. Number system conversion inaccuracy doesn't cause visible drawing errors. for colors and curves, that was my pixel talk.